# "no module named..." when running this python code

Tags: python, python-module

I have no idea what causes this error, this is as simplest as I could get, yet SO gives me hint that my question does not meet their quality standards so I must post this longer intro.

```
#===
# my_script.py
import myModule

#===
# myModule\__init__.py
import sys
from my_def import *

class MyModule:
  def __init__(self):
    pass

#===
# myModule\my_def.py
def my_def():
  pass

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_script.py", line 1, in <module>
    import myModule
  File "D:\test\myModule\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from my_def import *
ImportError: No module named 'my_def'
```

Comment: Didn't you ask this exact question a few minutes ago? [Yes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37501932/3001761), and it's not like you've improved it much; it's not just a longer intro that's required, it's one that explains the problem.

Comment: Make sure that your [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) contains the path to your module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `__init__.py`, add a `.` before `my_def`. The `.` means that it should be looking for the file in the same folder as the script itself, rather than relative to `my_script.py`.

```
from .my_def import *
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
sys.path.append("path_of_script")
```